# Запрос на принадлежность группе

Tags: запрос, sql-server, sql

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые форумчане!
Прошу у вас помощи. Застопорился на следующем:

**Исходные данные:**
Имеется таблица anytab в которой присутствуют поля id, descr, parentid, isgroup
У групп поле isgroup = 1. Уровень вложенности различен.

**Задача:**
Получить значения id и descr

**Условие:**
Вне зависимости от вложенности получить всех потомков по параметру @parent (@parent = parentid) кроме тех, где isgroup = 1, то есть кроме групп.

**Система:**
MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT @parentid AS id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT at.id
    FROM anytab AS at
    JOIN x
    ON at.parentid = x.id   
    WHERE at.isgroup = 1
)
SELECT at.id, at.descr
FROM anytab AS at
JOIN x
ON at.parentid = x.id
WHERE isgroup <> 1
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Помогло с небольшими изменениями:
WITH x AS (
    SELECT at.id AS id
    FROM anytab AS at
    WHERE at.id = @parentid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT at.id
    FROM anytab AS at
    JOIN x
    ON at.parentid = x.id   
    WHERE at.isgroup = 1
)
SELECT at.id, at.descr
FROM anytab AS at
JOIN x
ON at.parentid = x.id
WHERE isgroup <> 1

Answer (score 1):

**Решение в лоб:**

1. Написать функцию, например, `isAncestorOf(@parent_id, @child_id)`, которая будет while-ом поочередно вытаскивать родителей для узла, пока не дойдет до `@parent_id` или `null`.
2. Выбрать при помощи этой функции все узлы, у которых `isgroup <> 1` и результат `isAncestorOf` будет положительным.

Кроме того, можно попробовать воспользоваться рекурсией, которая поддерживается в MSSQL с 2005 и обойти нужное поддерево. На практике не пробовал, конкретнее сказать не могу.